# Find the residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin z }$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the  residue   of $ \frac{1}{\sin z }?$

My attempt : Here $f= 1$, Pole  will  be $z_k= k \pi$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

so $$ \operatorname{res}( f : z_k)  = \frac{1}{ 2\pi i}\oint_{|z- z_k|=1} \frac{f(z)}{\sin z} dz=1$$

So my answer is $1$  that is the  residue   of $ \frac{1}{\sin z }$ is $1$

Is its true?

Comment: I think $\operatorname{res}(f:z_k)$ should rather denote $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma  {f(z)dz}$. Thus, $f=1/\sin$. How did you get the value $1$ from the integral?

Comment: @Gary  because  here $f$  is constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the zeros of $\sin(z)$ are order $1$, we have
$$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=k\pi}\frac1{\sin(z)}
&=\lim_{z\to k\pi}\frac{z-k\pi}{\sin(z)}\\
&=\frac1{\cos(k\pi)}\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^k
\end{align}
$$

---

**Comment on the Answer in the Question**

If $z=a$ is an isolated singularity of $f$,
$$
\Res_{z=a}f(z)=\lim_{r\to0}\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-a|=r} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z
$$

Comment: thanks  u sir  @robjohn